# Scala IDE can't resolve dependeices

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I'm using the Scala IDE and I have the following build.sbt:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.2"
```

My class is:

```
object TextSplitter {

  def splitHalf(inputString: String) = {

      StringUtils.isEmpty(inputString)
  }
}
```

Eclipse can't resolve the dependency for StringUtils. In fact, I keep having problems with Eclipse/SBT to import anything outside the scala.* package.

I'm new to Scala, just want to try it out by building an actual example, but looks like I can't.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't integrate directly with sbt. You could manually add the dependencies to your eclipse build path, or you could use [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to generate eclipse project files with the correct dependencies based on your build.sbt.

Personally I would use maven (with the [scala maven plugin](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/)) rather than sbt, since eclipse *does* integrate with maven (using m2eclipse and [m2eclipse-scala](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-scala)), and will update dependencies based on your `pom.xml` without needing an external step to generate the correct project files.

Comment: Yes, I've found before that I have to use the sbteclipse plugin. I added the file ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt with the contents:

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.2.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.4.0")

However Eclipse still doesn't import anything, nor IntelliJ.

Would you be able to post a working build.sbt or tell me which directory to include as Build Path in Eclipse?

Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to run "sbt eclipse" on the command line to generate the eclipse project with the correct dependencies. Ideally you should probably close the project in eclipse beforehand, and open it after.
I don't have working sbt examples, I use maven myself.

Comment: The solution was to move the build.sbt into the version specific folder: ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt

Then sbt eclipse worked!

Thank you!